# Random number generator for certification using PHP

Tags: php, linux, php-extension

I'll try to explain my problem, if not the concrete solution, but at least theoritical thoughts would be good enough.

I'm writing random number generator - RNG (will run only on Linux (Ubuntu) server) and this code will be certified (the code/program anytime can be check using sha1/md5 hash and it has to much the certified version or something like that) 
so it will not be able to make changes anymore. Basically I use `mt_rand` function to generate values and several server parameters and `microtime` for seed (`mt_srand`). Still don't no if the code is good enough for certification, but that's not the main question.
Certification company said I will be required to give the source and the binary code for `mt_rand` function (maybe of `mt_srand` also). So how to do this in easiest and right way?

Found mt_rand function in `php_src_files\ext\standard\rand.c`
So somehow I should compile this extension and load to installed PHP as extension?

Im not new with php and linux, but I want to ask how to do it right, so I will have less headache 
deploying this RNG on different linux servers.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** Thanks for responses, but as I said, I'm not asking about, how to write RNG, but how to extract/compile/prepare/use part of php source for certification...

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _certification_?

Comment: This RNG will be used for betting company to generate some random values and this requires to certify that this RNG is really random. There are such companies who run a lot of tests/statistics on your code and if it pass you get certification to use RNG for such purpose.

Comment: Writing good PRNG-s is a full-time job by itself (and you can get a PhD working on that issue alone)... Did you read several math books (probabilities, statistics, ...) about them?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I think he's using the PHP function mt_rand(), which is part of the php distribution - and it is a "mersenne twister", so a proven "good" PRNG. I'm not entirely sure I understand what's going on, but I believe the mt_rand is "good".

Comment: Can you close this paranthesis: (the code/program a .... ?

Comment: @MatsPetersson the algorithm might be proven, but not its implementation in PHP, and what about correct seeding, etc.

Comment: Have a look at my comments on "creating a new (P)RNG" and links to tools http://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2012-12/msg00006.html

Comment: Did you ever get this certified? I am in a similar position.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you can read from [`/dev/random`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man4/random.4.html), which produces high quality random bits from environment noise. So this might serve you:

```
function dev_random_integer($min, $max)
{
    $stream = fopen('/dev/random', 'r');
    $randomBinary = fread($stream, 4); // read 4 bytes (32 bit)
    fclose($stream);
    $randomInt = unpack('l', $randomBinary); // convert to 32 bit integer

    $range = $max - $min + 1;
    return $min + ($randomInt % $range);
}
```

*Edit: you should not use that exact code, look at the comments below.*

Comment: You might not have enough entropy to serve all requests

Comment: @ydroneaud Good point. It still could be used to generate random numbers in advance. But that depends on how often random numbers are needed - I assumed that a betting company would not need to generate random numbers per request.

Comment: Additionally using modulo `%` might be the wrong things to do. Have a look at https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hasard/src/4a1be69a47eb1b2ec7ca95a341d4ca953a77f8c6/doc/common_errors.rst?at=default

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide the whole PHP sources and a binary PHP package (`php-cli`) that can be used to produces a binary stream to be checked against various tools. (You might ask your certification provider which operating system they support).

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, it would seem that it is a relevant one.

I recently built a casino game and used Zend/Math/Rand which provides cryptographically secure RNG. This passed RNG certification tests and my game has now been certified!

You can find the library on packagist: https://packagist.org/packages/gamblingtec/certified-rng

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I have updated the link to the actual package as the old articles seem to have been removed.